# All sides shadow outline in Unity NGUI

Tags: unity, ngui

How can I make such exactly the same shadow using NGUI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the image has Shadow + Outline. For text you should use "NGUI Label" component for gameobject. But there is only 1 effect could be applied to text: Shadow or Outline.
I believe you can make new class inherited from UILabel and make Effect field like an array, with multiplied effects.

Update:
I've found not elegant way how to do it without much pain and inheritance. There is a diff for UILabel.cs:

```
--- a/Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UILabel.cs
+++ b/Assets/NGUI/Scripts/UI/UILabel.cs
@@ -18,6 +18,7 @@ public class UILabel : UIWidget
        Shadow,
        Outline,
        Outline8,
+       ShadowAndOutline,
    }

    public enum Overflow
@@ -847,6 +848,7 @@ public class UILabel : UIWidget
            if (mEffectStyle == Effect.Shadow) return 2;
            else if (mEffectStyle == Effect.Outline) return 5;
            else if (mEffectStyle == Effect.Outline8) return 9;
+           else if (mEffectStyle == Effect.ShadowAndOutline) return 9;
            return 1;
        }
    }
@@ -1903,6 +1905,47 @@ public class UILabel : UIWidget

            ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, pos.x, -pos.y);

+           if (effectStyle == Effect.ShadowAndOutline)
+           {
+               pos.y /= 2;
+               pos.x = pos.y;
+               
+               offset = end;
+               end = verts.Count;
+
+               ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, -pos.x, pos.y);
+
+               offset = end;
+               end = verts.Count;
+
+               ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, pos.x, pos.y);
+
+               offset = end;
+               end = verts.Count;
+
+               ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, -pos.x, -pos.y);
+               
+               offset = end;
+               end = verts.Count;
+
+               ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, -pos.x, 0);
+
+               offset = end;
+               end = verts.Count;
+
+               ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, pos.x, 0);
+
+               offset = end;
+               end = verts.Count;
+
+               ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, 0, pos.y);
+
+               offset = end;
+               end = verts.Count;
+
+               ApplyShadow(verts, uvs, cols, offset, end, 0, -pos.y);
+           }
+
            if ((effectStyle == Effect.Outline) || (effectStyle == Effect.Outline8))
            {
                offset = end;
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: How can I make it? Could you please elaborate it more?

Comment: With inheritance it's a bit difficult than I thought.
But I found not elegant way how to do it without much pain. I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unity as a built-in [Shadow](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Shadow.html) component for UI elements. It's far from perfect but it's a good starting point.

Otherwise, you could duplicate the text, attach an outline component to the front text, and change the font color to the background text after moving it a little bit to get your shadow.

But I definitively advise you to use [TextMeshPro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84126), now free on the Asset store. [Here is a video about outline and soft shadow using TextMeshPro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfODpwcNsoE)